# Google Search API Missing Parameter q

Tags: api, curl, google-api, google-search, google-search-api

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have been following [these](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest) instructions fully.

Anyways, I am trying to use Google custom search API. I have my API and CS key.  I enter the following, with appropriate info filled in, but it says I am missing the q parameter when I am clearly not. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures


{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
    {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: q",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: q"
 }
}
```

Comment: Finally figured this out after an hour or so, just nest the url in single quotes (')

Answer (score 1):

The colon in the cx parameter must be URL encoded., i.e. `017576662512468239146%3Aomuauf_lfve`.  Using jQuery $.get with a params object will do this for you if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The Google API states that "q" or the query is necessary to run.

> Parameter name    Value   Description
>   Required query parameters
>   cx    string  The custom search engine ID to use for this request.
>   q     string  Query

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list